# I can't execute jade(pug) with express.js

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, pug

I'm having trouble with executing static files with express using templating engine pug.

i followed this two tutorials this from [default express.js site doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and [this tut from tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_templating.htm).

I'm using windows 8.1. I installed the (pug.js) templating engine. and this is my code;
I made an app.js file and here is its code;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

i made a index.pug file with directory /views. and here is its code;

```
    html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

Please tell me what is wrong. When i visit localhost:3000

i get this error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "./views"
   at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:579:17)
   at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:960:7)
   at C:\Users\PureTech\desktop\app\app.js:9:7
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at next (C:\Users\PureTech\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
```

Please help me, i struggled with this code for so long.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: Ben it is C:\Users\PureTech\Desktop\app\app.js and C:\Users\PureTech\Desktop\app\views\index.pug. I really appreciate your help, what do you think is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, try `path.join(__dirname, 'views')` instead of `'./views'`.

Comment: I'm getting error in the console. Ben all what i want to do now is to render a jade file with express to the browser. Can you please help me with an alternative and simple example . The web seem to not have enough good examples.

Comment: Make sure your file extension is `.pug` not `.txt`.

Comment: it is .pug file, here is another example i've tried this example                                     __________________var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views','./views');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000); and the same index.pug file as above  ______                             html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message _________________and i'm getting this error when i visit local host "Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "./views".

Comment: Could you `cd ` to **/views** directory, then run `dir` to check the file name? Because Windows 8 automatically hides file extensions (exe, txt, jpeg, etc).

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly:**

On line 3 in your code, you've forgotten to put the semicolon (`;`) at the end.

**Secondly:**

On this line

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' });
```

I don't know why you're using `title, message`. I usually use.

```
res.render('index');
```

I hope this helps!